# Split page details in crystal report to contain many data

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm using crystal report XI release 2 to make a report from SQL Server views

View 1 : OrderDetails
View 2 : SalesMen

OrderDetails contains only one record but SalesMen contains 5 records

i want to add both data in one page but i don't know how because when i add data from SalesMen it also repeat all data from OrderDetails and when choose Suppressed If Duplicated on all field in OrderDetails it's leave a blank area for unrepeated data which make very large spaces

Check the following images for more description

This how i want it to be like

[image: Needed View]

and this is how it looks like

[image: Not Needed View]

Note : And what if i have 2-3 views that contains several records and i want to show them in the same page?

Comment: If order details only contains one record, it should be in the group header, and the salesmen should be in the detail section.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables but what if i have 2 tables that contains several records and i want to show them up in the same page?

Comment: You'll need to explain more clearly what you're trying to do.  My guess, though, is to just join the tables on the related keys, and follow my initial instructions.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Okay here it is,
I have 5 views that i need to add them to a report in order to convert it to pdf, views content just like (view has only 1 record,view has 3 records,view has 5 records,view has 2 records,view has 6 records) and this is able to be changed depending on inputs, 

all records in all views start with the same field which is the Order Number

all what is need is to show all views content in this report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i've got what i was looking for
the solution is very simple, Create an sections inside details then create a sub reports and add it inside the section like the following steps

1 - Right click report body then select Section Expert

2 - From section tab click on details then insert sections as much as you want to add separate sections then press ok

3 - From crystal report main window click insert then click subreport

4 - name your sub report and add what you want

5 - insert the sub report inside the section you made

you can add it horizontal or vertical it's up to you.